# How to get latlong data back from an ArcGIS server

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geojson

I scraped data including geometry from https://tataruang.jakarta.go.id/server/rest/services/Batas_Administrasi_Update/Batas_Administrasi_DKI_Jakarta_Update_View/MapServer/0

where one sample of the data is
with headers as so

```
,"level_0","index","objectID1","WADMRT","WADMRW","WADMKD","WADMKC","WADMKK","KDGPUM","KDFPUM","KDEPUM","KDCPUM","KDPKAB","LUASWH","ID","JUMLAH_LAKI","JUMLAH_PEREMPUAN","TOTAL_PENDUDUK","OBJECTID","LUAS_RT","KEPADATAN","Shape__Area","Shape__Length","geometry"

0,"0","0","8290","007","9","GROGOL UTARA","KEBAYORAN LAMA","JAKARTA SELATAN","3174051004009007","3174051004009","3174051004","317405","3174","nan","GROGOL UTARARW9RT7","93.0","72.0","165.0","6953","0.02116857","7794.57426319","21172.168487695","630.6334219912901","POLYGON((11887810.585149335 -694170.5895844387, 11887763.520539563 -694165.5079235699, 11887733.498811511 -694164.5386431288, 11887730.736926513 -694166.26253862, 11887718.505617954 -694165.5847476447, 11887708.960233262 -694165.2094483451, 11887705.691726169 -694165.0809650233, 11887704.132918153 -694165.0196555209, 11887701.254616084 -694164.9065482351, 11887683.759617103 -694164.1724747906, 11887679.233432828 -694166.5222391136, 11887667.912458485 -694165.8979339052, 11887664.65649373 -694165.5811802321, 11887623.660770087 -694161.5911621357, 11887615.063062133 -694101.3551729687, 11887592.379592206 -694084.7866236303, 11887595.239916824 -694079.7619318971, 11887599.186837088 -694072.8287096185, 11887600.340042543 -694070.7181591626, 11887604.268097974 -694063.5291417049, 11887607.197230011 -694058.0292504401, 11887613.65029986 -694045.5252885219, 11887622.498295614 -694027.3965961878, 11887625.645998329 -694020.4939466066, 11887627.94142664 -694015.4602496751, 11887686.866177533 -694044.8803428481, 11887743.647055088 -694073.7799643101, 11887830.162171714 -694123.4825396386, 11887829.766520143 -694124.4487067807, 11887829.205197228 -694125.7989765694, 11887826.526890144 -694132.2415800181, 11887812.22292561 -694166.650102832, 11887810.585149335 -694170.5895844387))"
```

When I tried to check for the long lat on map the geometry data does not match any long lat in Jakarta.
However when I tried plotting the whole geometry polygons it represents the whole of Jakarta.

[image: plot geometry]

The geometry is correct when mapped out, however it does not show the longitude and latitude, how do I convert all polygon to longitude and latitude so that it matches to the location in Jakarta using Python?
My guess it's a  projected coordinate reference system however I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since that's an [ArcGIS service](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/arcgis-server-services.htm), you can specify the spatial reference you want it in. So instead of converting *after* receiving the data, ask for the data already converted.

Here's an example (asking for one feature) using the `outSR` paramater set to `4326` for the WGS84 projection.
https://tataruang.jakarta.go.id/server/rest/services/Batas_Administrasi_Update/Batas_Administrasi_DKI_Jakarta_Update_View/MapServer/0/query?where=OBJECTID%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&outSR=4326&f=geojson

Answer (score 1):

If you read the description of Map Service, it is providing this information

```
Description:

Service Item Id: 800b92167757427e91b1df13927884f6

Copyright Text:

Spatial Reference: 32748  (32748)

Extent:
XMin: 661393.6242680117
YMin: 9295186.947685957
XMax: 718733.2744904368
YMax: 9424774.182036337
Spatial Reference: 32748  (32748)
```

It means that your projection system is 32748(**WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S**), and try to scrap data from the service in GeoJSON